# why does any() work in python for a fibonacci sequence

Tags: python-3.x, functional-programming

In the case of `a` it works. However in case of `b it doesn't. Why does this happen?

```
a = [0,1]
b = [0,1]
any(map(lambda _:a.append(sum(a[-2:])), range(2,8)))
map(lambda _:b.append(sum(b[-2:])), range(2,8))
print(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: Do you mean why the second line using `map` doesn't do anything? `map`  is lazy and doesn't do anything unless it's asked for elements. You never ask it for elements, so it never runs. `any` forces it to run though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes `any` forces it to run, but only once since the first input will be truthy.  Evidently once is enough for the desired output.

Comment: @MarkRansom: No, the lambda function always returns the falsey value `None`, since that's the value returned by `list.append`. So `any` will consume the whole `map` iterator (which has its length limited by the `range` it's being passed).

Comment: @Blckknght you're right, thanks for correcting me.  That's why one-liners are so dangerous, especially when they're relying on side effects.

Answer (score 2):

This is extremely obfuscated code. Nobody would write code like this without an ulterior motive (such as Code Golf, or trying to wedge everything onto a single line), as it's doing a whole bunch of strange things that can much more simply be done some other way.

To address the thing you're asking about, `any` is called to consume all the values being produced by `map`. The return value of the `map` call is an iterator that lazily invokes the function it was given (a `lambda` expression) on successive values of the iterator it was given (a `range`). However, this code doesn't actually care about the values, which are all `None`. It wants the `lambda` function to be run *for its side effects*, which are appending values to the `a` or `b` lists. All of the values are `None`, since that's what `list.append` returns. Because `None` is falsey, the `any` function consumes all of them without stopping early (as it would do for any truthy value).

A much more natural way to write this code would be:

```
a = [0, 1]
for _ in range(2, 8):
    a.append(sum(a[-2:]))
```

Here it is much more clear that we don't care about the return values from `a.append`. That's because that method is something we're calling to modify `a` in place.